# The Principle of Condensation of Singularities

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces, baire-category

Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $\{T_{jk} : j,k \in\Bbb N\}$ be bounded linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. Suppose that for each $k$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $\sup\{\lVert T_{jk} x\rVert : j \in\Bbb N\} =+\infty$. Then there is an $x$ (indeed a residual set of $x$'s) such that $\sup\{\lVert T_{jk} x\rVert : j \in\Bbb N\} =+ \infty$ for all $k$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Since you are new, I want to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, what your thoughts on it are, and what you have already tried. This will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.  Please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** argue by contradiction, and apply Baire categories theorem to 
$$F_{k,n}:=\bigcap_{j\in\Bbb N}\{x\in X,\lVert T_{j,k}(x)\rVert_Y\leqslant n\}.$$