# Proof of Lemma preceding Principle of Condensation of Singularities

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, baire-category

Under the Wikipedia page for the Principle of Uniform Boundedness, we have the [Corollaries of the Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Corollaries). The third of these relates to the **Principle of Condensation of Singularities** (a question on which was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255223/the-principle-of-condensation-of-singularities)), however, the following Lemma is given as part of a motivation to achieving that result:

> [*Let $X,Y$ be Banach Spaces and*] Let $L(X, Y)$ denote the continuous operators from $X$ to $Y$, with the operator norm. If the collection $F$ is unbounded in $L(X, Y)$, **then by the uniform boundedness principle** we have:
>       $$R = \{ x ∈ X   :   \sup_{ T ∈ F} ‖ T x ‖_Y = ∞ \} ≠ ∅$$

I'm just wondering *how* exactly the Principle of Uniform Boundedness is being applied here; I was thinking to try and prove the result by contradiction and invoking PUB, but I don't see a way to do this without needing to make *two* deliberate incorrect hypotheses - in particular to assume that what we want to show holds *for all* $x\in X$ **and** to assume that for these $x$ we have that $\sup_{ T ∈ F} ‖ T x ‖_Y < ∞$. However, that would only tell us that *either one* of the hypotheses were wrong.

I wonder if instead one should work directly from Baire Category theory to prove the result - and indeed, perhaps, if that is what is meant by saying that UBP ensures this.

Could somebody give me a hint to set me on the right path to proving this result - as to whether I should use PUB directly, or work from Baire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $R =\emptyset.$

If $x \in X$, then $x \notin R$, hence there is $c_x \ge 0$ such that

$||Tx||_Y \le c_x$ for all $T \in F.$

The $PUB$ gives that $\{||T||: T \in F\}$ is bounded, a contradiction.

Comment: I see now how silly my question was ... my thanks